# mongodb php multiple collections

Tags: php, mongodb

A bit of weird issue - I am looking to enter data into two separate 
collections (same db) and I am getting totally weird results.   I am 
sure it is the way I am doing this but it is the results which have me 
a bit baffled.

Here is a snippet of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
    $mynewconnection = new Mongo();                                 // create new mongo connection 
    $collectionDB                  = $mynewconnection->Datadb;         // select db 
    $collectionA                 = $collectionDB->DataA;                // select collectionA 
    $collectionB                 = $collectionDB->DataB;                // select collectionB 


    /* Go off and chop up data and create CriteriaA/B */ 

     $insertA        = $collectionA->insert($criteriaA); 
     $insertB        = $collectionB->insert($criteriaB);
```

So what I am trying accomplish is to enter part of the data set into 
one collection and the other part of the dataset into another 
collection.   What is happening is that sometimes the data will be 
entered into Both collections (as desired) and other times data will 
be entered into just collectionA and yet other times data will be 
entered into just collectionB.

Anyone have any ideas on what I am missing or what would be causing 
this strange behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you fire a query to write something to MongoDB, it does not confirm whether the data is written to database or not. You need to see the page of php's manual for Write Concerns.

The link for the same is: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.writeconcerns.php